# Почему пустой TextView оказывается не пустым?

Tags: android, textview

Проверяю `TextView` на наличие текста так:

```
myText.getText().toString().equals("")
```

Результат `false`. В интерфейсе в эмуляторе пустая строка. В отладчике: `\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000`.

Как такое может быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перенес коммент:

Символ пустоты он же `ПУС, NULU`.
[Читаем](http://docs.cntd.ru/document/gost-27465-87).
Хотя я думаю этого не возникнет, если использовать `trim`.